# MongoDB - Mongodump utility takes forever to run

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, mongodump

I am trying out MongoDB. I have a very small db, like 4 documents in a collection, and that's it. I use MongoDB 3.2.7 on Windows 10.

I tried using the mongodump utility to backup the db. It just takes for ever, with no sign of it getting anywhere (been 4 hours +). I just closed the command shell after that. All I did is this on the command shell.

```
mongodump --db meantest
```

Also tried gzip ing it, and it does nothing as well. I know I could be doing something lame. I just can't see anyone else having this issue.

```
mongodump --db meantest --gzip
```

Can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: Have you had a look at the log to see if that sheds any light on the issue?

Comment: I tried. I have MongoDB installed in my program files, my db folder is on C:\data\db. I haven't seen any log file in the bin folder of the MongoDB installation, or the data folder. Where is the log file located, if any?

Comment: If you followed the [install guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) on the Mongo website, they would most likely be: `c:\data\log`

Comment: No such folder. In fact, I had to create C:\data\db folder manually, before I executed mongod (to run the server). There's no log folder.

Comment: Can you do a mongodump --verbose --db meantest with the verbose flag and post the output as well?

Comment: I gave up on that @Srijith, I am using a free sandbox db space, that mongo labs provides and hosts on the cloud.